# Haunted television set summons zombies from nearby graves

Tags: story-identification, books, horror, zombie

I watched the *Goosebumps* movie tonight with my son and I started feeling nostalgic about other books (not in the *Goosebumps* series) that I read when I was a kid. I've been scouring Google looking for this one book for the last hour or so, and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to figure out the title of one particular book from roughly the early 1990s. It must have been aimed at younger readers, because I recall checking it out from my elementary school library.

I think this book may have had a couple different stories in it. I don't recall the other stories because, frankly, they were kind of lame. But this story really scared me at the time. This was, I believe, the first story in the book.

The story was about an old television set, complete with a channel knob. The the protagonist of the story was, I believe, a younger person - a boy. I don't remember much of the "flesh" of the story, but here's the gist of it...

As the kid was flipping through channels on the TV late at night, he came across what looked like a cemetery scene in some grainy old black and white horror movie. He thought the cemetery looked familiar, and at that point, he noticed that it looked a lot like a nearby cemetery. As he continued to watch, the TV then showed the dead rising out of their graves in the cemetery. Wondering what he was watching, the kid noticed that the knob of the TV was stuck between two different channels. As the kid continued to watch, the TV showed zombies shambling down the road outside the cemetery, and then down *his* road, and then outside of a house - *his* house. The zombies began pounding at the door of the house on the TV, and at the same time, the kid could hear pounding at his front door.

I believe the story may have ended with the kid disabling the TV somehow (unplugging it?), and the pounding at the door stopped.

Again, just for clarification, this was not a *Goosebumps* book. I don't even know who the publisher was - if I had to guess, I'd have to say "Scholastic"? All I'm looking for is a title, either of the story or of the book itself.

Comment: Was it a series of books?

Comment: No, I believe it was a one-off book.

Comment: That sounds like something that could have been in one of the Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark series. There were three of them, with about 20 stories in each book.

Comment: I remember those books, but I don't think it was one of those. I know it *definitely* wasn't the first one or the second one.

Comment: @user14111 `The Case of the Strange TV Channel by Jaqueline W. Mcmann - A young man, watching a television broadcast with his family of the first unmanned probe to land on Pluto, ends up having his consciousness transmitted to the landing site, leaving his body behind in his living room, dead.`

Comment: @CreationEdge So much for that. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, that's not it. Even though that does sound like something I'd read! *thumbs up*

Comment: I've been looking through Google, and I still cannot find the book or the story. I've looked at authors J.B. Stamper, as well as R.L. Stine to see if either wrote the story, or the book. I think I might vaguely remember the title "What lurks on Channel X?"... Google searches only bring up references to the Rob Zombie song though...